# vue-gettext translate text

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am applying translation in vue 2.x and I am using "vue-gettext" but I am having a problem in some cases eg:

`<settings-group label="is a label" >`

`<settings-field label="is a label">`

In those cases I can't find a way to translate the label, I was looking for info and there is nothing, but maybe someone here could solve it...

Things I tried:

`<settings-field v-translate label="is a label">`

Doesn't work

`<settings-field label="{{<translate>is a label</translate>}}">`

Throw an error: Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead. For example, instead of , use <div :id="val".

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First option (preferred, since in vue3-gettext translate tag would be eventually removed):

```
<settings-group :label="$gettext('is a label')" />
```

Second option -- create slot `label` in `settings-group` component. Could be useful if you going to interpolate string based on some data from `settings-group`

```
# settings-group.vue
<div class="settings-group">
  <span class="label">
    <slot name="label" v-bind="{ count }" />
  </span>
...
```

```
# pages/settings.vue
<settings-group>
  <template v-slot:label="{ count }">
    <translate
      :translate-n="count"
      :translate-plural="%{count} elements"
      :translate-params="{ count }"
    >
     %{count} element
    </translate>
  </template>
</settings-group>
```